# Adding a spacing div after my content. How to stop my content divs going over bottom spacing div?

Tags: html, css, positioning, spacing

This is a page on a website I am building where I have the problem: http://www.tinytribes.co.uk/index.php?page=rooms

I am trying to add some blank space at the bottom of the page, after the footer (Cladswell Hall Farm, Cook... etc) so that the green hills graphics at the bottom can be visible when you scroll all the way to the bottom.  Instead of just being the footer of the content, which totally blocks the green hills.

I believe its because I have had to use position tags in my css for the content as I have elements as a background which would conflict.  This causes the content to fly over the top of my "bottomgap" div which would leave 200px after the final content div.

I am not looking for someone to give me an answer (as its quite a big ask!), just a point in the right direction.  I hope I explained it ok, its quite difficult!

Thank you.

Comment: It'd be very easy if you wouldn't position all your elements using `position: absolute;`. What is the reason you did this, because it doesn't look like it's necessary. You could use `margin: 0 auto;` to center the containers.

Comment: You are right. I'm still learning(this is my side hobby) and positioning has been quite a hard one for me to grasp.  I've decided to rebuild the site, using snippets of the old code I used, but revised how I position and center elements.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your major problem is that your content div is positioned absolute. You can try using the ::after css pseudo class to add a div with height say 80px; This might do the trick.

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3aafter)

hope this helps

Comment: In the end I decided to re-evaluate how I have positioned my elements.  This trips me up all the time, its quite a tough lesson for me to get over!  However the ::after psuedo class is really interesting!  Thanks for showing me this.

Answer (score 0):

Not a fan of your css but a fast solution and not so clean would be:

```
#bottomgap {
left: 50%;
margin: 0 0 0 -480px;
width: 960px;
bottom: 100px;
position: absolute;
bottom: -1900px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I tend to go a bit mad and very very rarely ask for any support so I usually chop and change until things work.  When I find everything works I go through and re-organise and tidy it up.  That said, I'm still quite a sloppy coder and I can only apologise!  I'll try and focus my efforts on best practices in future.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't apologise everyone is sloppy! :P

Answer (score 0):

add a div with the following style after `div mainpage`

```
style="
float :left;
position: relative;
bottom: -324px;
height: 59px;"
```